# C# FTP - Overwrite a file

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm trying to make a little application where I can select multiple files, set an interval and set the FTP server information. After that it uploads the files at the given interval.

I'm struggling at the FTP part. I could easily copy/paste some parts of codes from here, but I don't think that would help me. Basically I need to check if the file exists, if it does, delete it and upload the new version, if it doesn't exist just upload the file.

How could that be done in the most simple way? I'm not looking for tips on how to do it, i'm looking for the actually code preferable with comments on what does what.

EDIT: Based on the response from here, i think what i'm looking for is a way to override the file. Actually that was my first idea but i couldn't find anything about how to and then i just concluded that i manually needed to check and so on. I'm sorry for the mistake. Can someone give me a hint to what i need for overwriting?

Comment: Wait... you want our help but won't help us by posting the code you are having trouble with?  /boogle

Comment: Seeing as you did get someone to answer, it somewhat contradicts this comment, but....  Stack Overflow is not about having someone provide code to you.  We don't need you to be an expert, but just do your research and make your own attempts.  The community is very willing to help with code you are having trouble, but is less inclined to help when your only real question is `Show me the code to accomplish "x"`

Comment: Like i said. I've been looking around at the internet on how to do it. I'm new in programming and probably got a bit scared. One of the question i got is: Do i need to use or create different webrequest? I need to check, delete and upload but how do i do that in the most efficiently way without creating more webrequest than needed?

Comment: Why don't you simply overwrite existing files if your only action would be deleting already existing ones?

Comment: @Filburt - what if he only wants to delete it, not upload file?

Comment: @user2252334 I have tried FTP'ng, by default this gets overwritten.  why do you need to delete that file before uploading?

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this

```
var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.myworld.com/file.txt");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;

try
{
  FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

  // To delete file
  FtpWebRequest delRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
  delRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
  delRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
  FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse) delRequest.GetResponse();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   var response = (FtpWebResponse)ex.Response;
   if (response.StatusCode == FtpStatusCode.ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable)
   {
       //not exist
   }
}
```

Comment: other way to do w/o raising exception, get all files in the dir and check for existing one!

Comment: @AppDeveloper Easiest would be simply overwriting existing files since no specific action is needed for existing ones.

Comment: @Filburt - yes, but he need to delete it, not upload a file!

Comment: @AppDeveloper *"... check if the file exists, if it does, delete it and upload the new version, if it doesn't exist just upload the file."* reads like just overwriting to me. Unless *"new version"* implies something about the file naming logic which isn't specified.

Comment: Hmm. Didn't knew that i could overwrite the file. Maybe thats what i'm looking for.